# Best way to find most commonly occurring dictionary inside a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries where each dictionary has keys 'shape' and 'colour'. For example:

```
info = [
    {'shape': 'pentagon', 'colour': 'red'},
    {'shape': 'rectangle', 'colour': 'white'},
    # etc etc
]
```

I need to find the most commonly occurring shape/colour combination. I decided to do this by finding the most commonly occurring dictionary in the list. I've cut my method down to this:

```
frequency = defaultdict(int)

for i in info:
    hashed = json.dumps(i) # Get dictionary, turn into string to store as key in frequency dict
    frequency[hashed] += 1

most_common = max(frequency, key = frequency.get) # Get most common key and unhash it back into dict
print(json.loads(most_common))
```

I'm kind of new to python and I always end up finding out about some 1-2 line function that ends up doing what I wanted to do in the first place. I was wondering if a quicker method existed in this case? Maybe this can end up helping another beginner out because I couldn't find anything after ages of googling.

Comment: Are you absolutely wedded to a Dict for the internal structure? If the keys are consistent a `namedtuple` might be a better option. `namedtuple` is also hashable.

Comment: "I couldn't find anything after ages of googling" When I put `python most common element of list` into DuckDuckGo (or Google for that matter) I get multiple relevant results right off the top. What queries did you try?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ahhhh I searched that but I didn't see any specific examples of most common dict inside a list of dicts. I'll probs look back in a few months and realise the concepts were exactly the same but right now it's hard for me : (((

Comment: Well, yes. Why do you think it would matter to how you solve the problem, that the things inside your list are dicts?

Answer (score 5):

If the items in a list have consistent keys a better option is to use a `namedtuple` in place of a `dict` eg:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

# Define the named tuple
MyItem = namedtuple("MyItem", "shape colour")

# Create your list of data
info = [
    MyItem('pentagon', 'red'),
    MyItem('rectangle', 'white'),
    # etc etc
]
```

This provides a number of benefits:

```py
# To instantiate
item = MyItem("pentagon", "red")

# or using keyword arguments
item = MyItem(shape="pentagon", colour="red")

# or from your existing dict
item = MyItem(**{'shape': 'pentagon', 'colour': 'red'})

# Accessors
print(item.shape)
print(item.colour)

# Decomposition
shape, colour = item
```

However, back to the question of counting matching items, because a `namedtuple` is hashable `collections.Counter` can be used and the counting code then becomes:

```py
from collections import Counter

frequency = Counter(info)

# Get the items in the order of most common
frequency.most_common()
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

1. Instead of converting the dict into a particular string representation, grab the data you need from each. Making a tuple of the two string values gives you something hashable that works as a dict key.
2. The Python standard library provides `collections.Counter` for this exact counting purpose.

Thus:

```
from collections import Counter
info = # ...
histogram = Counter((item['shape'], item['colour']) for item in info)
# the most_common method gives a list of the n most common items.
shape, colour = histogram.most_common(1)[0]
# re-assemble the dict, if desired, and print it.
print({'shape': shape, 'colour': colour})
```

Comment: And, agreed, `collections.namedtuple` is likely a better data structure for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Using pandas would make your problem much simpler.

```
import pandas as pd

info = [
    {'shape': 'pentagon', 'colour': 'red'},
    {'shape': 'rectangle', 'colour': 'white'},
    # etc etc
]

df = pd.DataFrame(info)

# to get the most commonly occurring shape
# to get the count of values
print (df['shape'].value_counts())

# to get the most commonly occurring value
print (df['shape'].value_counts().argmax())

#or
print (df['shape'].value_counts().idxmax())
```

In order to get the most commonly occurring color, just change the shape to color
eg.
`print (df['shape'].value_counts())` to `print (df['colour'].value_counts())`

Not just this, pandas gives you a lot of other cool in-built function to play around.
To know more just google search [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and you will have it.

**NOTE:**
Please install pandas before using it.

```
pip install pandas
```

or

```
pip3 install pandas
```